# Catch Transaction Errors

Tags: c#, square

When I post a transaction with a input error, such as wrong cvv, an actual C# exception is thrown and the response is null. Therefore I obviously can't access the Errors list. Is there a better why to catch errors then parsing the Message value?

```
try
{
    sqResponse = transactionsApi.Charge(tokenInfo.LocationID, chargeRequest);
}
catch (SquareUp.Client.ApiException e)
{
    if (e.Message.Contains("VERIFY_CVV_FAILURE")) { error = "CVV is incorrect."; }
    else if (e.Message.Contains("VERIFY_AVS_FAILURE")) { error = "Postal Code is incorrect."; }
    else if (e.Message.Contains("INVALID_EXPIRATION")) { error = "Expiration date is incorrect."; }
    else if (e.Message.Contains("CARD_DECLINED")) { error = "Credit card has been declined."; }
    else if (e.Message.Contains("INVALID_CARD")) { error = "Credit card number is not valid"; }
    else
    {
     error = e.ErrorCode.ToString();        
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What errors list are you talking about?  Neither `ApiException` nor its base class `Exception` contain an `Errors` property.

Comment: This is where I am a little confused as a successful Charge action response contains an empty list of Errors. But when an error does occur the response isn't sent back and a ApiException is thrown. I was justing wondering is there is a cleaner way to determine the error code thrown than parsing the Message.

Comment: Well in the Github source, `ApiException` is only thrown in two places.  [This](https://github.com/square/connect-csharp-sdk/blob/96c75c77edf41798ae8a9dec650a241a5e088d0d/src/Square.Connect/Client/Configuration.cs#L98) is one of those places.  Perhaps you can replace the exception factory with your own.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. The Errors list returned is, of course, returned in the json result from the client side call.
[Errors](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/sqpaymentform/cookbook/notify-on-card-error?q=oauth%20error)